# Cannot get file sharing between Mac OS X 10.11 and Ubuntu 20.04 working (AFP or SMB)

Tags: networking, 20.04, samba, mac, file-sharing

I have a Mac OS 10.11 system and a PC running KDE Ubuntu 20.04 on my internal network.  I have been unable to get either system to share files with the other, despite following instructions on multiple web site.  Most of the web sites have outdated information, so it seems that things have changed significantly.  For example, the "afpfs-ng" package does not appear to exist in Ubuntu 20.

Can someone give me correct instructions for setting up file sharing between Mac and Linux?  I'd prefer to use AFP, but SMB is fine.

My user account on Ubuntu does have a password, but my account on the Mac does not.

As requested, the output of testparm -s:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        read only = No


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

"net usershare info --long" displays no output.  I'm guessing that's part of my problem.

Comment: What would help with the samba server part of this is for you to edit your question and add the output of these commands: `testparm -s` and `net usershare info --long`

Comment: It may be easier with NFS.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is still open…

Installing netatalk: `sudo apt install netatalk`and then editing the `afp.conf` file in `/etc/netatalk/` and adding a subdirectory owned by me, apart from `/home` did the trick. Accessing the ubuntu server with `afp://192.168.1.2` does give me the choice between Homes and Ubuntu in Finder and the files stored there.

```
; Netatalk 3.x configuration file
;

[Homes]
basedir regex = /home

[Ubuntu]
path = /var/www/ubuntu
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Bert!  This looks like a good answer (though I don't use Mac at all and don't try to share files with my partner's 3 Macs).  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ].